# Openpyxl: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, typeerror, openpyxl

```
  File "file_searcher.py", line 62, in <module>
    conditional_search(cellObj, current_sheet, db_entry)    
  File "file_searcher.py", line 19, in conditional_search
    print(current_sheet.cell(row = cellObject.row, column = (cellObject.column + 2)).value)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I am using openpyxl and I am getting this error on the line of code below. I have tried using str() and .format, but neither option works:

```
print(current_sheet.cell(row = cellObject.row, column = (cellObject.column + 2)).value)
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellObject.column` returns a string; something like "A" or "B" or "C". You get the idea. What you are, perhaps, looking for is `cellObject.col_idx`.

Basically, you want:

```
print(current_sheet.cell(row = cellObject.row, column = (cellObject.col_idx + 2)).value)
```

I hope this helps.